# Function to save values in the database? Values and rows that vary according to the choice of the combobox (executable code)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I have a hard time doing something simple enough. Sorry if I dwell a little in the explanation, but I do it to make the question clear even if it is a simple thing. I would like to update the selected and displayed values ​​in the database by means of a combobox.

I present an executable code. I have a combobox from which I select an element which searches for values ​​in the combobox (using `WHERE Choice =?`) And displays them in the textboxes. The values ​​are selected through two simple rows of a table in which in the lines there is the word selected in the combobox which is Choice 1 and Choice 2. For example, if in the combobox I select "Choice 1", the values ​​of a row of the database are printed which contains the text "Choice 1". This works correctly, no problem.

[image]

I have difficulty in creating and creating the `save` function to modify the values ​​(modifying them inside the textbox) and saving them (or better to say update them). The difficulty is that the values ​​shown in the textboxes vary automatically depending on the choice in the combobx. So I should write something to make Python understand which table row to modify and save depending on the combobox choice.

For example, in the example of the screenshot, selecting "Choice 1" from the combobox, I display the data 1 and 2 in the textboxes (because in row 1 of the database I have the WHERE Choice =?). I would like to be able to modify the numbers in the textoboxes and save them (or better say "update" them) in the same row 1 of the database. Same thing for Choise 2 and row 2 of the database.

Can anyone help me with the `save` function? Thank you

Executable code:

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.config(bg="gray")
root.state("normal")
  
conn = sqlite3.connect('....')
cursor = conn.cursor() 

#VIEW COMBOBOX'S ELEMENT
def combo():
    cursor.execute('SELECT choise FROM table')
    values = [row[0] for row in cursor]    
    return values

combo_choice=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 21)
combo_choice.place(x=10, y=10)
combo_choice.set("Select")
combo_choice['value'] = combo()

a = Entry(root,width = 4)
a.place(x=10, y=70)
b = Entry(root,width = 4)
b.place(x=60, y=70)


#RETRIEVE AND PRINT
def get_values(event):
    selected_value = combo_choice.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT number1, number2 FROM table WHERE choice=?', (selected_value,))
    value = cursor.fetchone()
    if value:
        #clean
        a.delete("0", tk.END)
        b.delete("0", tk.END)

        #insert           
        a.insert(tk.END, value[0])
        b.insert(tk.END, value[1])

time.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", get_values)


#SAVE THE CHANGES
def save():
    pass

button = Button(root, text="Save", command= save)
button.place(x=10, y=150)
```

The database is simply:

```
CREATE TABLE "table" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "number1"   INTEGER,
    "number2"   INTEGER,
    "choice"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Just do an `UPDATE` statement with the same `WHERE` condition as the `SELECT`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I believe this is the solution. I have dwelt a lot, when instead the solution is simple. But being new to Python, I don't know how. Can you show me please? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` statement similar to the `SELECT` statement that you use to display the current values.

```
def save():
    selected_value = combo_choice.get()
    number1 = a.get()
    number2 = b.get()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE table SET number1 = ?, number2 = ? WHERE choice = ?", (number1, number2, selected_value))
    conn.commit()
    pass
```